# Functor from Leibniz algebra category to Lie-Yamaguti algebra category

Tags: non-associative-algebras

Is there any functor from $\operatorname{Leib}_{\mathbb{K}}$ (Leibniz algebra category) to $\operatorname{LYA}_{\mathbb{K}}$ (Lie-Yamaguti algebra category)?

From Kinyon and Weinstein's [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25099070) I saw there exists one such functor (which I am stating below).

**My question:** Are there any other functors that exist from $\operatorname{Leib}_{\mathbb{K}}$ to $\operatorname{LYA}_{\mathbb{K}}$?

---

### Functor from $\operatorname{Leib}_{\mathbb{K}}$ to $\operatorname{LYA}_{\mathbb{K}}$ given by Kinyon and Weinstein:

Starting from a Leibniz algebra $(L, \cdot)$ one can construct a Lie-Yamaguti algebra structure on $L$ via the following binary and ternary operations:
$$[a,b] := a \cdot b - b \cdot a \quad \{a,b,c\} := - ~ (a \cdot b) \cdot c$$
This construction defines a functor from $\operatorname{Leib}_{\mathbb{K}}$ to $\operatorname{LYA}_{\mathbb{K}}$.

As any morphism $f: (A, \cdot_A) \to (B, \cdot_B)$ (where $(A, \cdot_A)$ and $(B, \cdot_B)$ are Leibniz algebras) in the Leibniz algebra category becomes a Lie-Yamaguti algebra morphism $f: (A,[\cdot,\cdot]_A, \{\cdot, \cdot, \cdot\}_B) \to (B, [\cdot,\cdot]_B, \{\cdot, \cdot, \cdot\}_B)$ in the category of Lie-Yamaguti algebras.